# Определение ближайшей точки по координатам

Tags: php

Есть массив с координатами(X,Y) и есть главная точка(X,Y)
Как определить ближайшую точку из массива к главной точке?

Comment: А почему очевидный метод (пробежаться по массиву, запоминая текущий минимум) не сработал?

Comment: Мне сама формула интересна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Point {
    public $x, $y;

    function __construct($x, $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }

    function distanceTo(Point $point) {
        $distanceX = $this->x - $point->x;
        $distanceY = $this->y - $point->y;
        $distance = sqrt($distanceX * $distanceX + $distanceY * $distanceY);
        return $distance;
    }

    function __toString() {
        return 'x: ' . $this->x . ', y: ' . $this->y;
    }
}

$a = new Point(0, 0);
$points = array(new Point(0, 2), new Point(0.5, 0.3), new Point(1, 1), new Point(-1, -2));

$curNearestPoint = $points[0];
$curNearestDistance = $a->distanceTo($curNearestPoint);
foreach ($points as $point) {
    $distance = $a->distanceTo($point);
    if ($distance < $curNearestDistance) {
        $curNearestDistance = $distance;
        $curNearestPoint = $point;
    }
}

echo 'nearest point: ' . $curNearestPoint;
```

Comment: Можно было бы еще оформить поиск ближайшей точки как метод класса Point, принимающий на вход массив точек и возвращающий ближайшую.

Answer (score 1):

Перебор массива через [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php), сравнение и запоминание ближайшей точки.

Comment: Мне бы формулу подсказать

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @MaksimMorozov: `(current.X - p.X) * (current.X - p.X) + (current.Y - p.Y) * (current.Y - p.Y)` даёт квадрат расстояния, минимизируйте его.